# How can I dynamically insert a new template into the DOM with Ember?

Tags: jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an Ember.js app. In the main template I have a help button that when clicked should display a CSS tooltip. I have the tooltip is a separate Handlebars template.

What I'm trying to do is handle the click event to insert the popup into the DOM and display it.  I cannot figure out how to insert new templates into the DOM using Ember.

Here's my template where the help button is displayed:

```
<div id="status_help" class="icon_help" {{action "helpClicked"}}></div>
```

Here's my primary view:

```
var checkbox = Ember.Checkbox.extend({
    templateName: 'checkbox',
    helpClicked: function(e) {
        // Not sure what to do here
    }
}));

var tooltip = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'tooltip'
});
```

So I'm not sure what to do in the event handler to render the tooltip template and inject it into the DOM to be displayed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a new view and append it to the DOM using `Ember.View`'s `append` or `appendTo` methods.

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'a_template'
})

var view = App.MyView.create();

// Append the view to the document body
view.append();
// ...or append to any element described using
// a jQuery-compatible selector.
view.appendTo('#my-div');
```

Comment: There is also a `replaceIn` method, see https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/255bd707a73c905fa6e14ac76f134642e9802667/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L704-724.

Comment: I was doing it backwards. I was calling append on the parent view to try to append the child. I'll give this a shot, thanks.

Comment: How would this be done in Ember 2.x now that Views have been deprecated?