# How do I append a view to a div inside of a view?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to append a view to a placeholder div by id, in line with the answer here: [How can I dynamically insert a new template into the DOM with Ember?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200495/how-can-i-dynamically-insert-a-new-template-into-the-dom-with-ember).

```
insertInfoBox:function (context) {
    var infoBoxView = App.LocatorInfoBox.create({
        context:context
    });

    infoBoxView.appendTo('#infoBoxHolder');
},
```

I get the following error: Uncaught Error:

**assertion failed: You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead.**

The 'infoBoxHolder' div is nested within another view, but is not itself a view.  If I set up infoBoxView as a child of the parentView (if I changed the parent to a container view), I'm unclear on how to insert the view into the child div 'infoBoxHolder' and not directly into the parent container view's root element.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to do this, but you can use the didInsertElement function. Something like:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        $('#elementId').append(...);
    }
});
```

The way I would do it would be through a template, something like:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{#if someCondition}}{{MyApp.MyOtherView valueBInding="..."}}{{/else}}');
});
```