# Render a template with model outside of rootElement with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am adding Ember.js to an existing rails application and am using the `rootElement` option when creating my `Ember.Application`.

There are a couple places outside of this `rootElement` where I would like to insert a small ember template bound to a simple `Ember.Object` model.

I've created a jsfiddle with an example that I hope makes what I'm looking for clear: http://jsfiddle.net/amiel/x9fCz/2/

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [new ember view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200495/how-can-i-dynamically-insert-a-new-template-into-the-dom-with-ember), with the template name matching my handlebars template. Then instantiated it in an ember initializer.

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: "clock_view",
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    var view = App.ClockView.create();
    view.replaceIn('#now');
  }
});
```

See full example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amiel/2FsxA/1/

I'm not going to accept my own answer just yet to see if anyone else has a better way to do this.

**UPDATE**: Here's another possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/amiel/2FsxA/3/

TL;DR:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.setupClock();
        this._super(controller, model);
    },
    setupClock: function() {
        var view = App.ClockView.create();
        view.replaceIn('#now');
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems a rather good solution! Very clean. Only downside is that the code for placing the view isn't in your 'normal' location where another developer would search for it.

Comment: @JordyLangen Thanks! Yeah, I agree. This seems only slightly better than having this view related code in `Ember.Application.create({ ready: ...`. Maybe there is a hook in `ApplicationRouter` or `ApplicationController` that would be a better place?

Comment: DEPRECATION: Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported. [defaultContainer#lookup]. You should check this in order to make this work smoothly in last Ember https://gist.github.com/stefanpenner/5627411

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the `DEPRECATION: Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported` message, you'd have to create a childView within the ApplicationView#didInsertElement.

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var view = this.createChildView(App.ClockView);
        view.replaceIn('#now');
    }
});
```

The App.ClockView#controller will now be the App.ApplicationController as well.